# How to add empty rows to grid and fill the columns and then submit in EXTJS

Tags: rest, extjs

How to add rows to grid and add some values with in the columns
 and then submit the data as json format to the rest api in EXTJS

Json data like :

```
[
 {
   "col1"  : "john",
   "col2"  : "xyz",
   "col3"  :  "01/05/2018"
 },
 {
   "col1"  : "bush",
   "col2"  : "xpao",
   "col3"  : "01/08/2018"
 },
 .......
 ]
```

Some thing like above
 I want to add data  as above in grid column and submit to API in EXTJS

Thanks in Advance -:)

Comment: Your question is not clear provide more information. Exactly what you need

Comment: In grid panel i want to add row dynamically (on click add row) with the given model  and submit all enters rows to the api as array, As shown in question

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add data as above in grid column and submit to API

For this, You need to use the [`store.sync()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-sync) and [`rowediting`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing.html) plugin for grid.

1. **store.sync()** synchronizes the store with its [proxy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-proxy). This asks the proxy to batch together any new, updated and deleted records in the store, updating the store's internal representation of the records as each operation completes.
2. The `Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing` plugin injects editing at a row level for a Grid. When editing begins, a small floating dialog will be shown for the appropriate row. Each editable column will show a field for editing. There is a button to save or cancel all changes for the edit.

You can check with working **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2l36)**

> **Note** :  I have used dummy api name you need to use your actual api with store proxy for create, read, update and delete records.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

            storeId: 'gridStore',

            fields: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],

            autoLoad: true,

            pageSize: 25,

            remoteSort: true,

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'POST',
                api: {
                    read: 'data.json',
                    update: 'your_update_api',
                    create: 'your_create_api',
                    destroy: 'your_delete_api'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    encode: true,
                    root:'data'
                }
            },
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

            title: 'Add Row Example',

            store: 'gridStore',

            height: 300,

            border: true,

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            tools: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
                tooltip: 'Add New Record',
                handler: function () {
                    let store = this.up('grid').getStore();

                    store.insert(0, {
                        col1: '',
                        col2: '',
                        col3: ''
                    })
                }
            }],
            columns: [{
                text: 'col1',
                dataIndex: 'col1',
                flex: 1,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                }
            }, {
                header: 'col2',
                dataIndex: 'col2',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                },
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'col3',
                dataIndex: 'col3',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    dateFormat: 'd/m/Y'
                },
                flex: 1
            }],

            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                })
            ],

            bbar:['->',{
                text:'Submit Changes',
                handler:function(){
                    this.up('grid').getStore().sync()
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In real life situation you will need the following components:-

1- Ext.data.Model -> [Record] to map your model and add you validations and logic if needed.

2- Ext.data.Store -> [Set of records] which will consume the model.

3- Proxy which will handle the call the the web service, proxy can be added to the model or the store.

4- Grid Row Editor or cell row editor to be able to insert you data.

This is a working example [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l31)

When you press Add data the model is created [record], you can start editing the data based on the editor property in the columns, this record is stored in the grid store so you can add as many records as you need.

When you press submit the store.sync is responsible to read the proxy apis and send the data to your service, you will need to open your dev tools network inspect to see the data sent in the request as json.